# Mysql Finding the smallest n from a column

Tags: mysql, sql-limit

So in MySQL you can find the smallest n using sub queries or limit or even TOP in some cases. But I wanted to know if it was possible to find the smallest N without using any of these? I was told this was possible but have no idea where to start. I assume I have to inner join multiple times but beyond that, I am clueless.

For reference, suppose I have a column called salary with the following data (10,20,30,40). If n=2, that means I need to find the second smallest salary, which would be 20.

Comment: So, SO isn't a code producing site. Post your attempts first

Comment: There is no possibility of using TOP in MySQL.

Comment: You might like to read about the `LIMIT` clause here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html The `TOP` query modifier is specific to Microsoft and Sybase, but it is not supported by MySQL or other brands of SQL database.

Comment: It's possible. What would you like to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS salary;

CREATE TABLE salary (i INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO salary VALUES (10),(20),(30),(40);


SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             GROUP_CONCAT(i ORDER BY i)
          ,',',2)
       ,',',-1)n 
  FROM salary;
+------+
| n    |
+------+
| 20   |
+------+
```

or (specifically for where n=2)

```
SELECT MIN(i) x 
  FROM salary 
  LEFT 
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(i) y FROM salary) j 
    ON y = i 
 WHERE y IS NULL;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|   20 |
+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL 8.x you can use the `DENSE_RANK()` window function, as in:

```
select salary
from (
  select salary, dense_rank() over(order by salary) as rn from t
) x
where rn = 2 -- this gets the second smallest salary
```